# Unable to log into Windows 10 remote desktop using PuTTY/RDP

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop, putty

I have been using PuTTY/RDP to log into a windows 10 machine.

I use PuTTY  to log into mydomain.com. Under "Connection/SSH/Tunnels" I have entered "localhost:3389" as the source port, and "myremotepc:3389" as the destination.

After I have logged in, I open up the Windows Remote Desktop Connection and enter "localhost" or "localhost:3389".  I have entered the correct username "myname" or "MYLOCALPC\myname".

I get the error message: Remote Desktop Connection "Your computer could not connect to another console session on the remote computer because you already have a console session in progress".

Next I tried entering "127.0.0.2:3389" as the source port, and "myremotepc:3389" as the destination.  I opened up Windows Remote Desktop and connected to 127.0.0.2.  I now get the prompt for a user name and password, but when I enter the correct credentials I get "Your credentials did not work. The credentials that were used to connect to 127.0.0.2 did not work. Please enter new credentials"

Can anyone help me?

Comment: If I'm following your setup correctly, the username should be entered as `myremotepc\myname` instead of `mylocalpc\myname`

Comment: I got this working by using myremotepc\myname, and entering another port as the source port - eg. 127.0.0.2:3390